# Python XMl Parser with BeautifulSoup. How do I remove tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For a project I decided to make an app that helps people find friends on Twitter.

I have been able to grab usernames from xml pages. So for example with my current code I can get `<uri>http://twitter.com/username</uri>` from an XML page, but I want to remove the     `<uri>` and `</uri>` tags using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Here is my current code:

```
import urllib
import BeautifulSoup

doc = urllib.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=travel").read()

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(''.join(doc))
data = soup.findAll("uri")
```

Comment: Do either of the answers below help?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use BeautifulSoup to parse twitter, use their [API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) (also don't use BeautifulSoup, use [lxml](http://lxml.de/)). To answer your question:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

resp = urllib.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=travel")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read())
for uri in soup.findAll('uri'):
    uri.extract()
```

Comment: The code you gave me still has has the Uri tags in between the twitter.com/username

Comment: It shouldn't, all the tags should be stripped from `soup`, `str(soup).find('uri') == -1`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about BeautifulSoup, `text` is what you need to grab the contents of each `<uri>` tag. Here I extract the information into a list comprehension:

```
>>> uris = [uri.text for uri in soup.findAll('uri')]
>>> len(uris)
15
>>> print uris[0]
http://twitter.com/MarieJeppesen
```

But, [as zeekay says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721160/python-xml-parser-with-beautifulsoup-how-do-i-remove-tags/6721199#6721199), [Twitter's REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) is a better approach for querying Twitter.